# How TCP server knows where to send message? (client A or client B?)

Tags: c#, vb.net, chat, tcpclient, tcpserver

- Tcp server implemented
- Tcp client implemented

server started

client A connect

client B connect

client C connect

client A send message to server(but he wants to send to client B or C or to all of them)

E.g.: Let's say that...

> Server needs to send this message to client B

```
How client A will send the message so that server will know that A want to 
send this message to B or C etc..
```

Should client A together with the message to send the ID let's say of client B so server extract ID and after somehow knows that will forward that message to client B?

..Or is completely wrong how i think chat app works?

Should each client work as a server too? and when client wants to talk with client B the same logic applies?

I have searched online for examples but most of then rely on simple server and one client.

I don't need code, just the idea so i can understand how this works.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Clients don't send data directly to other clients, they send their data to the server and it's the server's responsibility to deliver it to the intended target(s). For a public chat room, the targets is "all other clients besides the one who sent me the data". However, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: For future reference, StackOverflow exists to help existing code. If you're saying "I don't need code", then you have posted the question to the wrong forum. What you are talking about is the difference between a client-server architecture and a peer-to-peer architecture. Client-server is easier. Yes, you will include information about the intended recipient in your client requests. There is no other way for the server to determine which of the clients to forward the message to.

Comment: You need to implement some logic of your own in order to know where to route the messages. The message data coming from the client will need to include something which identifies the intended recipient, which the server can use to make the decision about where to send it next. Just like when you send an email, or post a letter. Of course, you could also include the ability to create a group chat and thus route the message to multiple recipients. So yes, your idea is basically correct

Comment: "should each client work as a server too?" that is somewhere between Peer to Peer or having each client as failover servers. But generally the client is not suiteable to act as server. Try a basic client-server before you think about anything that fancy.

Comment: Generally each client is given a SessionID. Something they send with every request to get around the statelessness of this whole thing. Cookie are the common example of a SessionID. Depending on the stituation, you may want a user ID for login purposes. In that case only ever publish the userID. It is the client UI's job to translate those ID's into human readable names and vice versa. You only work with session or better user ID's.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/microsoft/Build-Mobile-App-with-Chat/blob/master/02%20Tutorial%20Guide.md

There is code and logic for non TCP chat using server push technologies and service bus to accept messages and deliver them.

For TCP, same principles apply. Receive the message on a certain topic, add it to some queue or a topic (better for chatrooms with multiple people) and deliver from a background job to all people interested on the topic.

You will of course need some kind of persistence layer to store messages and track delivery, history, likes and the sort.